# How to get cumsum using custom aggregation function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have `DataFrame` like mentioned below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2014,2017,2014,2016,2016],'prod':['A','B','C','D','E']})
```

I can get it using this

```
df.groupby('year').count().cumsum() ##

    prod
year    
2014    2
2016    4
2017    5
```

I want to make this result using **Custom Function only** where is `custom_func` can be passed

```
df.groupby('year').agg({'year':custom_func})
```

I have tried so far

```
def count_sum(series):
    se = pd.Series(np.ones(series.shape[0]))   
    return se.sum()

df.groupby('year').agg({'year':count_sum}) ## it is just returning as 'count' function
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `cumsum` as applied for output of aggregation - here one column `DataFrame`, so is necessary chain it after `agg`:

```
print (df.groupby('year').agg({'year':count_sum}))
      year
year      
2014     2
2016     2
2017     1

df1 = df.groupby('year').agg({'year':count_sum}).cumsum()
print (df1)
      year
year      
2014     2
2016     4
2017     5
```

Comment: Hi Actually I want `cumsum` to be included inside in custom function

Comment: @Akhilesh - I know, but not possible, because `agg` working with each group separately and `cumsum` working with output of aggregate function.